# Curve Fitting to Represent Any Data

Tags: polynomials, curves, floating-point

I'm a programmer seeking to take a bunch of data and represent it as a curve. Specifically, I want to take several hundred/thousand (floating) points and represent those points to a specified level of accuracy (e.g. at least to the nearest 0.01) as a curve. **Note**: this data will not pass the vertical line test (it won't be representable as a function), and I ideally do not want to split it up into different curves.

(Forgive me if "curve" is the wrong word to use here. Should I refer to it as something else, e.g. polynomial? I'm not sure.)

Here is my reasoning: I would like to be able to store all of this data in as little space as possible at the cost of a little computation. I figure the only way to do that - to compress data that may not have very much redundancy (and even if it did, the compression wouldn't be as significant as I am hoping for) - is to represent the data algorithmically somehow. (I actually feel kind of smart for coming up with this idea, even if it already is in practice and I don't understand the math behind it. :)

Is this doable, and if so, how? How would the math behind this work?

If what I am wanting to achieve is absolutely impossible or would take far too much computation to be practical, that's okay. I have a contingency list of things I would sacrifice if necessary in order to have a next-best attempt:

1. I could try sorting the data according to X positions in order to make the result a function.
2. I could curve-fit only, say, a dozen points at a time.

but of course I would prefer not to have to do either of these.

Also, if it makes much of a difference, these points are 3 dimensional. (2 dimensional answers are welcome though, if that makes it easier to answer or simpler to explain.)

Thanks,

Comment: You can always use a cubic [spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: Well I don't want anything that is piecewise, as that would significantly raise the compression rate.

Comment: If the curve is smooth enough you could try to throw away a large portion of the datapoints and reconstruct the curve using splines.

Comment: I only want to *represent* the data as a curve for compression; the data will typically not be smooth or curve-like at all. I think one of us is misunderstanding the other: the goal is for the result to have as few numbers as possible, whereas from what I know splines would increase the amount of data required for storage. Can a bunch of random points that are not a function be represented as a single curve?

Comment: Can you post an example of a small subset of your data that demonstrates that, indeed, it doesn't pass the vertical line test?

Comment: You indicate that you're not completely confident in your use of terminology - "forgive me if 'curve' is the wrong word to use here" - yet you throw around terms with very specific meanings like 'smooth' (in your comments). In my opinion, the relevant properties of your data are not explicit in your question; you're leaving a lot of guesswork for anyone who is trying to help you. Yet, in spite of you being the one who has asked for help, you denigrate those who have spent some time and effort to help you - whether via comments or answers. Best of luck to you and your "kind of smart" ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure this is alot like how JPEG image compression works. They take in a bunch of data points (pixels) and using the principles of Fourier transforms figure out which combination of Cosine curves when added will produce the original data.

Here is a nice link

http://nautil.us/blog/the-math-trick-behind-mp3s-jpegs-and-homer-simpsons-face

The more modern compressors use "Wavelets" instead of Cosine but the basic idea still sounds really similar to your idea.

Comment: Excellent read!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for Gaussian Processes.  Which are totally awesome.

[image: Gaussian Process Example Plot]

To be frank, it's been many years since I did it, but here's the python code that I wrote years ago, in the hope that it will help you.

```
#This uses Gaussian processes algorithm from page 19 of CW2

from scipy import *
from bisect import *
from scitools.all import *  #imports numpy & scitools
import scipy.linalg as la
from scipy import interpolate

#optimal adjustment for residual is given by sum(ydata-yCS)/4n

#generate data set to practive with (will be array of x & y)
n=1000
x=linspace(0,1,n)
y=sin(10*x**2)*exp(1/(x+0.1))*(x-0.3)*(x+0.1)*(x+0.8)

random.seed(12341)
xnoise=random.normal(0,0.01,n)
ynoise=random.normal(0,0.01,n)

xdata=x+xnoise
ydata=y+ynoise

#covariance function
sigmaf=5   #sigma_f  (noise in f)
sigman=0.01       #sigma_n   (noise in x)
l=0.1           #length scale
def k(x1,x2,sigmaf,l):
    "Covariance function"
    return (sigmaf**2)*exp(-((x1-x2)**2)/(2*(l**2)))

K=zeros((len(xdata),len(xdata)))
for i,x1 in enumerate(xdata):
    for j,x2 in enumerate(xdata):
        K[i][j]=k(x1,x2,sigmaf,l)
K=matrix(K)

K2=K+(sigman**2)*eye(len(xdata))
L=la.cholesky(K2,lower=True)
y2=la.solve(L,ydata)
alpha=la.solve(L.T,y2)

def fstar(xstar,xdata,alpha,sigmaf,l):
    """calculate the expected value of f for a given x"""
    kstar=zeros(len(xdata))
    for i,x in enumerate(xdata):
        kstar[i]=k(xstar,x,sigmaf,l)
    return dot(kstar.T,alpha)


ycalc=[]
for xstar in x:
    ycalc.append(fstar(xstar,xdata,alpha,sigmaf,l))


plot(x,ycalc-y)
#plot(x,y,'-',xdata,ydata,"+",x,ycalc,title="sigma_f=%f, sigma_n=%f, and l=%f"%(sigmaf,sigman,l),legend=("actual","data","GP"),hardcopy="plot.png")
```

In brief, you're figuring out a matrix (alpha in the code), and using that to generate your estimate (fstar in the code is the function that does that for a given x).

Comment: Before I go digging through the code to figure out what's going on, what's the output like? Is it an equation for a curve or something of the like, is it reversible back to the original data, and does the data need to pass the vertical line test?

Comment: So the code generates some noisy data, and then generates a function to fit the data. The fit is function-free.

Comment: The graph that I posted is what is generated. The matrix is quite big, but it smooths out the data as you can see in the graph. If you have data that's smooth and noisy, you can get rid of a lot of the data and store the matrix, which will allow you to recover the data. But it is going to be lossy, because it's smoothing the data.

Comment: The code shows how to generate a matrix from a data set (alpha), and how to recover (smoothed) dependent data from a X value and alpha (fstar).

Comment: It depends a great deal on the nature of your data. I'm assuming it's somewhat smooth, somewhat noisy, and the data points are dense. If it's just a scattergram of x-y data, and you need to recover the exact points, then you'd need a different compression algorithm

Comment: Having read your comment (" the data will typically not be smooth or curve-like at all"), I think your curve approach is not the right one.  You're just looking for standard compression algorithms.  There's hundreds out there, and you probably don't need to program it yourself